# ui select change from btn-default to btn-primary

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2

I'm using ui-select-directive (angular-ui/ui-select) with the bootstrap-theme.

for displaying the select-control it uses the btn-default-class.
I would prefer to use the btn-primary-class.

when i open the Debugger inside my browser and Switch the classes it looks exactly how I want it ;)

this is my select-control

```
                <ui-select ng-model="currentCtrl.Field.Format.Format.Name" theme="bootstrap" id="fieldtype" ng-disabled="currentCtrl.RecordViewType!=0">
                    <ui-select-match placeholder="Search...">{{$select.selected.Name}}</ui-select-match>
                    <ui-select-choices repeat="item.Name as item in currentCtrl.SomeItems | filter: $select.search">
                        <div ng-bind-html="item.Name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                    </ui-select-choices>
                </ui-select>
```

**this is how it Looks like before:**
[image]

**this is how it Looks like after changing the class.**
[image]

Is there a way to simply Change this class for all select-boxes?

Comment: Hi. Did you succeed to do this? If so, it would be nice to post it as the answer.